# How to fix: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I am setting up an asp.net core web-api hosted on IIS. The api has some logic for creating XML documents which should be stored in a folder directly under the C: drive of the server. The flow is as follows:

The client sends a request which is processed and stored in the database. Once the database transaction is complete an XML document is generated with some data. I have stored the path where this document should be generated in the appsettings.json file as follows:

```
"ProtocolPath": {
"PathToFolder": "C:\\some_folder"
}
```

In my code i have a class which stores a Path variable and initializes it via the constructor:

```
public string Path { get; set;}

public ProtocolService(object entry, IConfiguration config)
{
    _config = config;
    Path = GetProtocolPath();
    _entry = entry;
}

private string GetProtocolPath()
{
  try
  {

    if(!Directory.Exists(_config.GetSection("ProtocolPath")
    .GetValue<string>("PathToFolder")))
    {            
       Directory.CreateDirectory(_config.GetSection("ProtocolPath")
      .GetValue<string>("PathToFolder"));
    }

    StringBuilder pathBuilder = new 
    StringBuilder(_config.GetSection("ProtocolPath").GetValue<string> 
    ("PathToFolder"));
    pathBuilder.Append(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
    pathBuilder.Append(".xml");

    return pathBuilder.ToString();

   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      var msg = $"{ex.Message} : {ex.InnerException}";
      Console.WriteLine(msg);
      throw;
    }
  }
```

I have some logic which generates an object which needs to be serialized to XML. For that i use an extension class.

```
public static class XmlGenerator
{
    private static FileStream _xmlFileStream;
    private static XmlWriter _xmlWritter;

public static void ConvertToXml(this Protocol obj, string pathToProtocol)
    {
        try
        { 
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Protocol));
            _xmlFileStream = new FileStream(pathToProtocol, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
            _xmlWritter = XmlWriter.Create(_xmlFileStream, new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Async = true, Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 });
            serializer.Serialize(_xmlWritter, obj, new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty }));

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var msg = $"{ex.Message} : {ex.InnerException}";
            Console.WriteLine(msg);
        }
        finally
        {
             _xmlWritter.Flush();
             _xmlWritter.Close();
            _xmlFileStream.Flush();
            _xmlFileStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Locally the folder is correctly created under C: and the XML files are also correctly generated. However on the server where the API is hosted, none of this happens and the logs only show:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path :
```

Comment: Please put `var bob = _config.GetSection("ProtocolPath")
    .GetValue<string>("PathToFolder");`, and log the value of `bob` **on the server**. What is its value? _Please don't guess._

Comment: Which exact line is producing that error?  What are the actual runtime values used on that line when you debug?

Comment: @mjwills Logs on the server show the value for _config.GetSection("ProtocolPath").GetValue<string>)("PathToFolder"); as empty. It looks like the the config file is not being read properly.

Comment: Could this have anything to do with application rights on the server? I don't have much experience with that.

Comment: Add log feature line by line in `GetProtocolPath` to check whether it returns the expected path. To check whether it is related with permission, try to specify your path with the value under your project instead of `c:`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's problem with your `GetProtocolPath()`. `pathBuilder` not return path format.

```
private string GetProtocolPath()
    {
        try
        {
            string path = _config.GetSection("ProtocolPath").GetValue<string>("PathToFolder");
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            StringBuilder pathBuilder = new StringBuilder()
                .Append(path)
                .Append("\\")
                .Append(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))
                .Append(".xml");

            return pathBuilder.ToString();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var msg = $"{ex.Message} : {ex.InnerException}";
            Console.WriteLine(msg);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but the path format is correct. The problem seems to be that the config file is not being properly read on the server.